# Menubar not consistent using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am creating a menu using **Bootstrap 4**. This is my current code:

```
<div class="row mx-2">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle='dropdown'>
            Option 1
        </div>
        <div class='dropdown-menu'>
            <div class='dropdown-item' style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="dosomething()">
                DDO11
            </div>
            <a href="abc.php" class='dropdown-item'>DDO12</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle mx-3" data-toggle='dropdown'>
            Option 2
        </div>
        <div class='dropdown-menu'>
            <div class='dropdown-item' style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="dosomething()">DDO21</div>
            <div class='dropdown-item' style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="dosomething()">DDO22</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-dark col mx-2" onclick="dosomething()">Option3</div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle='dropdown'>
            Option 4
        </div>
        <div class='dropdown-menu'>
            <div class='dropdown-item' style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="dosomething()">DDOP41</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-dark col mx-2"><a href='ABC.php' style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">Option 5</a></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the dropdown buttons are as wide as text, while the non-dropdown buttons are too wide and taking up all the left over space. I need all the option buttons to be of same width.

I tried assigning *width:20%* and also tried *col-*-** on all of the parent option buttons, but nothing worked.

What else can be done to achieve equal width for all option buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You need add `CSS` like below in your CSS file

```
.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: unset !important; // add width as per your need
}
```

[**Live Demo**](https://codepen.io/RammmohanBandaru/pen/dwMdxe?editors=1100)

Hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Using the Bootstrap approach, I suggest you to made a grid (a grid have 12 columns) with one row and five columns with class `col-sm-2` (On **XS** screens the layout should be different because of the small total width you have). To make this centered, just add a `offset-sm-1` class to the first `col-sm-2` item. And to make buttons have the full-width of the column that wraps it, just use the [btn-block](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#sizes) class. I made changes to your example to make this work:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">

  <div class="offset-sm-1 col-sm-2 mb-1">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="btn btn-info btn-block dropdown-toggle" data-toggle='dropdown'>
        Option 1
      </div>
      <div class='dropdown-menu'>
        <div class='dropdown-item' style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="dosomething()">
          DDO11
        </div>
        <a href="abc.php" class='dropdown-item'>DDO12</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2 mb-1">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="btn btn-info btn-block dropdown-toggle" data-toggle='dropdown'>
        Option 2
      </div>
      <div class='dropdown-menu'>
        <div class='dropdown-item' style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="dosomething()">
          DDO21
        </div>
        <div class='dropdown-item' style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="dosomething()">
          DDO22
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2 mb-1">
    <div class="btn btn-dark btn-block" onclick="dosomething()">Option3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2 mb-1">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="btn btn-info btn-block dropdown-toggle" data-toggle='dropdown'>
        Option 4
      </div>
      <div class='dropdown-menu'>
        <div class='dropdown-item' style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="dosomething()">
          DDOP41
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2 mb-1">
    <div class="btn btn-dark btn-block">
      <a href='ABC.php' style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">Option 5</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4, the `row` class should *only* be used to contain `col*` and not other elements like `btn` and `dropdown`. The other elements are placed *inside* the columns. From the Bootstrap docs...

> "Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding
>   (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them... In
>   a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns
>   may be immediate children of rows."

Put the dropdown and btn in columns. Use the [auto-layout grid](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#equal-width) (`col` or `col-auto`) to control the equal widths. For buttons that fill the width of their parent use `btn-block`.

For full equal width use `col`...

```
<div class="row mx-2">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="btn btn-info btn-block dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Option 1
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="btn btn-dark btn-block mx-2">Option3</div>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

For "shrink to fit" content width use `col-auto`...

```
<div class="row mx-2">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="btn btn-info btn-block dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Option 1
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="btn btn-dark btn-block mx-2">Option3</div>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo of both options](https://www.codeply.com/go/8KVhz1tcfG)